# Where can I download cuparticle.cls file

Tags: document-classes

When I compile my document. LaTex shows the error:

> File, 'cuparticle.cls' not found.

Where can I find this file.

The file is for Cambridge University Press. Actually, the Journal is Forum of Mathematics, Pi. In read me file, the following is instructed:

You need the following file:

```
cuparticle.cls
```

Please use the documentclass option fmp'. For example:

```
\documentclass[% 
  fmp, times, 
]{cuparticle}
```

Here is the link((https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/forum-of-mathematics-sigma/information/instructions-contributors)
) to zip file containing LaTex file which I try to compile. Please click on, "LaTeX template files for submission" inside the link.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is "cup" short for Cambridge University Press -- CUP for short? If so, have you inquired with CUP?

Comment: Could you show us your code as well?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the `zip` file from the given link is that there is no file  `cuparticle.cls` but `cuparticle v2.cls`:

[image]

Copy the given files to a new directory and rename `cuparticle v2.cls` to `cuparticle.cls`.  Then you can compile the given file `fms-template.tex` file without that message you got ...

Answer (score 0):

The [Journal is Forum of Mathematics, Pi](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/forum-of-mathematics-pi/information/instructions-contributors) author instructions page provides a page to download a zip file that contains [cuparticle.cls](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-file-manager/file/575eaf947f586d69154725be). It looks like the class was developed by [RVT](http://vm106.river-valley.com/wiki/index.php?title=Cuparticle.cls) but the [download link](http://download.river-valley.com/cuparticle/cuparticle.cls) on the wiki appears dead and the wayback machine isn't helpful.